# UINavigationBar custom background with overhang (iOS 5)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I'm trying to make this (excuse the quick-and-dirty mockup):

[image]

It's a UINavigationBar with a custom background image. However, the image needs to overhang the bottom of the navigation bar. The image is an irregular shape (the white bits on my mockup are transparent and should show the view controller's view through the gaps).

I'd really rather not have to modify every possible view controller to draw the overhanging bit. Can anyone think of a clever solution to make this work?

I'm supporting iOS 5 only, so no need for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I managed it myself: I made the overhang part of the background a separate image, and added it as a subview of the navigation bar:

```
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackground-overhang"]];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, newNavC.navigationBar.frame.size.height, newNavC.navigationBar.frame.size.width, iv.image.size.height);
    [newNavC.navigationBar addSubview:iv];
    newNavC.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: don'tcha just hate it. As soon as you post to stackoverflow you solve it yourself minutes later. Happens all the time. Argh.... Nice job BTW.

Comment: hehe. It does happen quite frequently. On the flip side, posting on Stack Overflow does seem to help, because somehow it prompts my brain to come up with the solution!